How can I control the device speaker (On/Off) from my app during a call in Android 14 and later?
I expect the speaker to switch on or off based on user input during a call, but the code executes without any errors, and there’s no change in the speaker state.
I’ve checked permissions and ensured that the methods are being called, but nothing seems to work. I'm testing on Android 14 and using the latest version of the relevant libraries. Any insights on what might be going wrong would be appreciated!”
This is my current code service
package com.example.ivrapplication.activity
import android.telecom.Call
import android.telecom.CallAudioState
import android.telecom.InCallService
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet

class CallManager {
companion object {


    var inCallService: InCallService? = null
    private val listeners = CopyOnWriteArraySet<CallManagerListener>()

    fun getSupportedAudioRoutes(): Array<AudioRoute> {
        return AudioRoute.values().filter {
            val supportedRouteMask = getCallAudioState()?.supportedRouteMask
            if (supportedRouteMask != null) {
                supportedRouteMask and it.route == it.route
            } else {
                false
            }
        }.toTypedArray()
    }
    fun getCallAudioRoute() = AudioRoute.fromRoute(getCallAudioState()?.route)

    fun setAudioRoute(newRoute: Int) {
        inCallService?.setAudioRoute(newRoute)
    }

    private fun getCallAudioState() = inCallService?.callAudioState

    fun onAudioStateChanged(audioState: CallAudioState) {
        val route = AudioRoute.fromRoute(audioState.route) ?: return
        for (listener in listeners) {
            listener.onAudioStateChanged(route)
        }
    }

    interface CallManagerListener {
        fun onStateChanged()
        fun onAudioStateChanged(audioState: AudioRoute)
        fun onPrimaryCallChanged(call: Call)
    }}
}

This is my Call Manager Code
package com.example.ivrapplication.activity
import android.telecom.Call
import android.telecom.CallAudioState
import android.telecom.InCallService
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArraySet
class CallManager {
companion object {


    var inCallService: InCallService? = null
    private val listeners = CopyOnWriteArraySet<CallManagerListener>()

    fun getSupportedAudioRoutes(): Array<AudioRoute> {
        return AudioRoute.values().filter {
            val supportedRouteMask = getCallAudioState()?.supportedRouteMask
            if (supportedRouteMask != null) {
                supportedRouteMask and it.route == it.route
            } else {
                false
            }
        }.toTypedArray()
    }
    fun getCallAudioRoute() = AudioRoute.fromRoute(getCallAudioState()?.route)

    fun setAudioRoute(newRoute: Int) {
        inCallService?.setAudioRoute(newRoute)
    }

    private fun getCallAudioState() = inCallService?.callAudioState

    fun onAudioStateChanged(audioState: CallAudioState) {
        val route = AudioRoute.fromRoute(audioState.route) ?: return
        for (listener in listeners) {
            listener.onAudioStateChanged(route)
        }
    }

    interface CallManagerListener {
        fun onStateChanged()
        fun onAudioStateChanged(audioState: AudioRoute)
        fun onPrimaryCallChanged(call: Call)
    }

}
}

